# How can I use a foreach loop to check which elements of an array are equal to a given string?

Tags: perl, foreach

My foreach loop is not working as I wish it to. I want it to loop through the array and find when one element is present and when the element is not present. However, I get all of them saying `Not an apple`.

```
@fruit = ('apple','orange','pear');

foreach(@fruit){
     if(@fruit != 'apple'){
          print "Not an apple\n";
     }
     else{
          print "Is an apple\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are compared using `eq` (equal) and `ne` (not equal). `$_` is implicit `foreach` variable and it should be used like,

```
if ($_ ne 'apple')
```

If you want to use explicit loop variable:

```
foreach my $v (@fruit) {

     if($v ne 'apple'){
          print "Not an apple\n";
     }
     else{
          print "Is an apple\n";
     }
}
```

Now, why do you get all `"Not an apple\n"` printed for all elements of `@fruit`? First, the `!=` results in the left-hand side being evaluated in scalar context which gives the number of elements of `@fruit`, i.e. *`3`*. On the other hand, `'apple'`, not being numeric, evaluates to *`0`* in this numeric comparison for equality. Therefore, the `if` condition, for each element of the array reduces to:

```
if (3 != 0) {
```

and, of course, that holds for every element of the array, regardless of what that array element is.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modules strict and warnings will help you avoid these mistakes. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a bit more modern way of writing Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @fruits = qw( apple orange pear );
for my $fruit ( @fruits ) {
   if ( $fruit ne 'apple' ) {
      say "$fruit is not an apple";
   }
   else {
      say "This is an apple.";
   }
}
```

You made several mistakes in your code, and if you had `use warnings;` in your code, Perl would have told you about them. This is why `use warnings` should always be included. The `use strict` forces you to use stricter syntax which means that you can't use *barewords* (you must quote strings and make sure functions are property declared). And, you have to *declare* your variables (usually with `my`).

You had:

```
foreach (@fruit) {
```

which means that each fruit would be in the `$_` variable, but instead, you were using

```
if ( @fruit != ... )
```

In your `if` statements. That is, you're comparing the entire `@fruit` array to the value. Also, the `!=` is for numeric comparisons only. You want `ne` for string comparisons. The `use warnings` would have caught both of these errors.

Your `if` statements should have looked like:

```
if ( $_ ne '...' ) {
```

However, I don't usually recommend to use `$_` for a variety of reasons. It's original purpose was to make the code easier to read, but it usually fails at that. Instead, I usually will use an explicit variable name:

```
for my $fruit ( @fruits ) {
```

instead of

```
foreach (@fruit);
```

Also note that I use plurals when naming arrays and hashes (since they're usually groups of objects anyway), this way, I don't end up with `@fruit`, `$fruit`, and `%fruit` which can be confusing (although legal). You could add a suffix (i.e. `@fruit_list`) to help clarify an array from the individual variable too.

I also like using `say` instead of `print` because `say` automatically adds that `\n` to the end of my printed output. I get the `say` command when I add in the pragma `feature qw(say);` to my program.

I also like using `qw(...)` to define one word lists. It's cleaner and easier to read than using quotes and commas. Note I do not add commas between my fruit names.

Comment: +1 You might want to point out `@fruit` on the LHS of `!=` evaluates to the number of elements in the array.